# Add a <div> around the ul of a wordpress dropdown

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my HTML before converting to wordpress I had two divs surrounding the UL element, but now as wordpress is automatically creating the dropdown nav, I need to define it to add these two divs (and the second div's CLASS) around the generated UL.

I've included the original HTML of my nav as it should be used.

live site: http://bit.ly/1k90oaO

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="active">
    <a href="/HTML/index.php" class="active">HOME</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="/parts.php">PARTS</a>
    <div>
        <div class="nav-column">
            <br />
            <ul class="full-width">
                <li class="nav-li-item"><a href="/HTML/parts.php">Beltings &amp; Tensioners</a></li>
                <li class="nav-li-item"><a href="/HTML/parts.php">Beltings &amp; Tensioners</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Current setup in wordpress.
**functions.php**

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

function register_theme_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header-menu'   =>   __( 'Header Menu' )
        )
    );  
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus' );
```

header.php

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'menu'       => 'header-menu',
        'menu_class' => 'nav',
        'container'  => 'true',
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `'items_wrap'` option of [`wp_nav_menu()` in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: I tried but it keeps wrapping <div>'s around each of the LI elements, instead of one set of DIV's around the entire UL.